# Finding a lowest value in a list using lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I have a code which saves my data into a `.txt` file, then I use code (below), which looks for the lowest value in a specific column and saves it to another file with other information attached to this row. The output looks like this and I will cover two cases when I got this same error.

My code:

```
    rows = []
    with open("S:/Workflow/Testresults/measurements.txt", mode='r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=" ")
        for row in reader:  # each row is a list
            rows.append(row)
    minimus = min(rows, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
    dipolemoment = (float(minimus[3]) * ((2*6.532) * pow(10, 22) / (1.06 * pow(10,-10) * 4.5 * cos(radians(int(minimus[0])))))) * pow(10,-24)
```

Error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "S:/Workflow/NewestDecomp/Decomposition13062019.py", line 198, in <module>
>     minimus = min(rows, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
>   File "S:/Workflow/NewestDecomp/Decomposition13062019.py", line 198, in <lambda>
>     minimus = min(rows, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
> ValueError: could not convert string to float:
> ```

## First

Output:

```
30 295.5746708644463
31 287.2952638886134
32 278.71824911973124
33 269.851301784405
34 260.7054651033139
35 251.29568775900006
```

In this case the script works, but if I have a number that exceeds 100 in the first row I got an error.

## Second

Output:

```
30 239.69282467921443 0.4676188470692765 
31 233.26309732696078 0.4676188470692765
32 226.55527422794984 0.4676188470692765
33 219.5700525651719 0.4676188470692765
34 212.31067697178025 0.4676188470692765
35 204.78347831156816 0.4676188470692765
36 196.99928467633828 0.4676188470692765
```

Here if I try to use the code I got this error. It doesn't matter whether I have number higher that 100 in the first column.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `* pow(10, -24)` is much more legible as either the suffix `e-24` or `* 1e-24` or `/ 1e24`.

Comment: Looks like you have empty lines in the file.

Comment: @MadPhysicist what do you mean by empty lines? I have a `" "` to separate columns, that's all.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You're right, I have empty column. The only thing left to solve is why I got this error when the number in the first column exceeds 100?

Comment: Ok solved this problem.

Comment: Given that you don't supply sufficient information to properly answer your question, or for it to be if much use to further readers, I recommend deleting if your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are likely seeing an issue with the format of the text file that you read.

When I run the code snippet

```
rows = []
with open("test.txt", mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=" ")
    for row in reader:  # each row is a list
        rows.append(row)
    minimus = min(rows, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
```

with your first example in `test.txt`, but modified to have an integer larger than 100 in the first column, I do not reproduce the error. Similarly, when I run this code snippet with the second example verbatim, I do not reproduce your error.

The error that you see

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

shows that the string that cannot be converted is empty. If it were a non-empty string, for example, the string `notafloat`, it would show as

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: notafloat
```

An example of where column two would be an empty string is if there were multiple spaces between the first and second column in a row. In that case, you can use `skipinitialspace=True` as an option in `csv.reader`, which will skip any additional spaces after the delimiter.